# MySQL indexes stop working

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework

I am working on News website, the table (news) contain about 200,000 rows.
I use Zend framework 1.
the website was working very good, but from a week ago, I have found some errors in data retrieve from the queries.

I use zend paginator, like this:

```
 $paginator = Zend_Paginator::factory($select);
 $paginator->setItemCountPerPage(10);
 $pageCounter = $paginator->count();
```

so $pageCounter  return 0,

when I try to debug the error, I have tried to drop the indexes from the database table and create the index again, then the problem was resolved the website back to work again.
but every couple days this problem back again.
the tables I use is:

```
    CREATE TABLE `news` (
 `news_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `category_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `news_type` enum('text','photo','video') DEFAULT 'text',
 `news_title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 `news_url` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 `news_date` datetime NOT NULL,
 `news_image` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
 `video` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
 `news_source` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `author_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `news_brief` text,
 `news_content` mediumtext,
 `meta_title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 `meta_description` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
 `meta_keywords` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
 `status` tinyint(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
 `news_read` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
 `old_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `old_section_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `old_section` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
 `lang` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
 `featured` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `in_timeline` tinyint(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `is_highlight` tinyint(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `home_exclusive` tinyint(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `home_articles` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `home_articles_selected` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `home_mostread` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `video_featured` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `photos_featured` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `party_featured` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `party_activity` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `sport_featured` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `fnoun_featured` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `special_reports` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `mainnav` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 PRIMARY KEY (`news_id`),
 KEY `News_Category_idx` (`category_id`),
 KEY `News_Type` (`news_type`),
 KEY `News_Date` (`news_date`),
 KEY `News_Read` (`news_read`),
 KEY `old_id` (`old_id`),
 KEY `Sources` (`news_source`),
 KEY `Authors` (`author_id`),
 KEY `Featured` (`featured`),
 KEY `Articles` (`home_articles`),
 KEY `Mostread` (`home_mostread`),
 KEY `video_featured` (`video_featured`,`photos_featured`),
 KEY `party_activity` (`party_activity`),
 KEY `sport_featured` (`sport_featured`,`fnoun_featured`),
 KEY `old_section_id` (`old_section_id`),
 KEY `old_section` (`old_section`),
 KEY `old section id` (`old_section_id`),
 KEY `old section` (`old_section`),
 KEY `articles_selected` (`home_articles_selected`),
 KEY `URL` (`news_url`),
 KEY `special_reports` (`special_reports`),
 KEY `mainnav` (`mainnav`),
 KEY `status` (`status`),
 KEY `in_timeline` (`in_timeline`),
 KEY `is_highlight` (`is_highlight`),
 KEY `home_exclusive` (`home_exclusive`),
 KEY `party_featured` (`party_featured`),
 FULLTEXT KEY `news_title` (`news_title`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=167614 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

the columns (status - featured - in_timeline - is_highlight) type was (ENUM) but I have changed to (tinyint)
It works for a few days, but the problem come back again.
so I have to drop the indexed and create it again.
I don't know what is the problem?
can anyone help, please.

The Explain Query, it's the same when the problem happen and after I drop the indexes and create it again.

```
SQL query: Explain SELECT `N`.`news_id`, `N`.`news_title`, `N`.`news_url`, `N`.`news_image`, `N`.`news_type`, `N`.`news_date`, `N`.`is_highlight`, `N`.`news_brief`, `C`.`category_name`, `C`.`category_url`, `C`.`category_color`, `NT`.*, GROUP_CONCAT(T.tag_name separator ",") AS tags, GROUP_CONCAT(T.tag_url separator ",") AS `tags_urls` FROM `news` AS `N` INNER JOIN `news_categories` AS `C` ON C.category_id = N.category_id AND C.status = "1" LEFT JOIN `news_tags_relation` AS `NT` ON NT.news_id = N.news_id LEFT JOIN `news_tags` AS `T` ON T.tag_id = NT.tag_id WHERE (N.status = "1" AND N.category_id = "22") GROUP BY `N`.`news_id` ORDER BY `N`.`news_date` DESC;
```

Rows: 4

```
This table does not contain a unique column. Grid edit, checkbox, Edit, Copy and Delete features are not available.
```

the table in the attached images
[image]
[image]

Comment: is the highest id 2147483647?

Comment: No, the highest id is 167616.

Comment: If you have 200,000 records then maybe you are hitting limits in indexing or memory and it might be worth a trawl through the logs. I would look at deleting some of the keys (especially on the old_* fields). Perhaps the best way is to accept the fact it will die, and run a cronjob in the early morning to reload the indexes. Good luck

Comment: Have you checked your logs to see if it gives any clues? I'd recommend checking your mySQL and Application logs to start with, to see if there is anything that gives you a hint.

Comment: First of all, don't listen to Ewen. You should not cure the symtoms with dirty workarounds but address the problem itself. Your question is totally unclear. What does "indexes stop working" mean exactly? One could guess, that it means they aren't used and you got poor performance (which wouldn't surprise me, seeing your table definition), but you're writing that you get `$pageCounter return 0` which suggests that you got wrong data, which has nothing to do with indexes. Please add as much details as possible to the question, including result from `EXPLAIN <your select query>`.

Comment: I'd do the following steps: 1. enable slow query log with `long_query_time`=1 . 2. wait till the indexes "stop working" - i.e. you see the symptoms you're describing now. 3. open slow_query_log file and watch the count() or pagination query and it's execution time. 4. copy raw query and compare the execution time before and after index recreation. 5. update your question with EXPLAIN of the same query before and after the problem re-occurs

Comment: This problem going to occur over and over, 
the explain query is added in the question above.

Comment: 2nd Alexey's suggestion above. Plus sharing how much ram your hardware has and show variables like '%cache%'; show variables like '%innodb%';